# Why do I have inconsistent behaviour using fprintf?

Tags: c, string

As far as I know, `fprintf` takes an pointer to a array of chars as an argument, and prints it. I don't know "when" it stops though. Take the following examples:

Assume: `print_s` is

```
void print_s(const char* s) {
    fprintf(stdout,"%s",s);
}
```

Example 1:

```
char c[6];
c[0] = 'a';
c[1] = 'b';
c[2] = 'c';
c[3] = 'd';
c[4] = 'e';
print_s((char*) c);
```

output:

```
abcd // e not printed!
```

Example 2:

```
char c[6];
c[0] = 'a';
c[1] = 'b';
c[2] = 'c';
c[3] = 'd';
c[4] = 'e';
c[5] = 'b';
print_s((char*) c);
```

output:

```
abcdb // works as expected
```

Example 3:

```
char c[6];
c[0] = 'a';
c[2] = 'c';
c[3] = 'd';
c[4] = 'e';
print_s((char*) c);
```

output:

```
a<someGarbage>cd // works as expected
```

Example 4:

```
char c[6];
c[0] = 'a';
c[1] = 'b';
c[2] = 'c';
c[3] = 'd';
c[4] = 'e';
c[5] = '\0';
print_s((char*) c);
```

output:

```
abcde // works as expected
```

Comment: Ex 1: `char c[5];` not initialized.  Add `char c[5] = '\0';` Ex 2: Missing null character in `c[]`.  Hmm  looks like home work rather than your own code.

Comment: Example 4 is the only one that works properly, because the array passed contains the `'\0'` terminator that is required of a "string". If any other example worked it was "lucky" to find that terminator by accident, not by design.

Comment: Regarding ex2: if I make the size `c[7]` and don't change anything, it will still print `abcde`, so I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: @WeatherVane so if I want to do something like `print_s((char*) "abc")`, then C compiler will create an array like: `['a', 'b', 'c', '\0']`? Why doesn't this also happen with array declaration, e.g. if I declare c[6], why is c[5] not automatically set to `\0`?

Comment: @emihir0, in that case, it is likely that the value at c[6] (for a 7 char array) is already populated with a null byte to terminate the string. However, this is not necessarily standard behavior across all machines, so just because initializing the char array with an extra byte seems to resolve the issue on your end does not mean it is the proper solution, as it will most likely not be cross-compatible.

Comment: @emihir0 Just because it doesn't totally explode in that one test you did does not mean the code is correct. In C this is called Undefined Behaviour. Code with UB has unpredictable behaviour. It may appear to "work" sometimes but then blow up next time.

Comment: `why is c[5] not automatically set to \0`. You need to read the C standard. It's not defined to initialise like that (assuming your variable is auto/local and not static/global).

Comment: @emihir0 please do some googling, it's already been explained *ad infinitum* out there. But yes, `"abc"` is a **string literal** which has the `'\0'` terminator applied, so `sizeof("abc")` will be `4`.

Comment: So if this array was global, does that mean it would be initialised to `\0` (ie. `c[5]`)?

Comment: No, global is irrelevant, if you initialise each element of an array in the fashion of your question, no `'0'` is supplied unless you explicity put one, because the compiler does not know you intend it to be a "string". It may be for some other purpose.

Comment: Global variables have static storage, which means they will be initialized to 0 (in the case of an array, all elements will be 0).

Comment: Why do you say Example 2 is working as expected? What happened to the `e` in `c[4]`?

Comment: FYI, you don't need to cast `c` to `(char *)`. When you pass an array to a function, it's automatically converted to a pointer.

Answer (score 6):

Please note that when you declare character arrays and initialize their elements one-by-one, you need to provide values for the characters continuously starting from the first one, and the last character should be given a null `'\0'` value.

Example:

```
char a[6];
a[0]='a';
a[1]='b';
a[2]='c';
a[3]='d';
a[4]='\0';
```

This would declare the array `a` as the string `"abcd"`.

If you fail to initialize in a similar way, your string is prone to getting garbage character values, which cannot be correctly interpreted by any I/O function, and would give unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

Section '7.19.6.1 The fprintf function 8(s)', top of page 280, of the [ISO/IEC 9899 C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) I looked at has the following to say about strings printed by `fprintf()` (using the `%s` format specifier):

> Characters from the array are written up to (but not including) the terminating null character. If the
>   precision is specified, no more than that many bytes are written. *If the
>   precision is not specified or is greater than the size of the array, the array shall
>   contain a null character* (emphasis mine).

Even the behaviour you note as 'expected' is unspecified if the NUL terminator is absent. The behaviour you are seeing is dependent the implementation of the compiler and that of the system your code is running on. On different system or with a different compiler, you are likely to get a different result for your examples 1-3.